# How to show byte array elements in Listview?

Tags: listview, arrays

I have a byte array:

```
byte[] myArray={6,23,44,34,56,23,32,13,67,45};
```

I want to show all elements in a listview like this:

[image]

What command should I use?

Comment: This question is missing something important: the languages and platform you plan to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayAdapter，just like this:

```
{
byte[] myArray={6,23,44,34,56,23,32,13,67,45};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArray);//Use the system has achieved good XML file simple_list_item_1
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```